# Downloading and Using jquery.jOrgChart.js

Tags: jquery, download

I found a reference to jQuery's org chart. I want to download the library from a trusted source, but all I find is in people's sample code. Does anyone know where I can find such a download? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the original source.

http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/jquery/orgchart/jquery.orgchart.js

CSS and images:

http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/jquery/orgchart/

UPDATE:

Looks like there is an updated version available here (forked from the original version):

https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart/

That's how open source works, anyone can take a project and add new things to it and make it there own (depending on the license).

Comment: Do you know this to be a trusted source? Does jQuery not make it's own libraries?

Comment: If you read the source code of `jquery.orgchart.js` it has the same domain name in the copyright. Unless you've seen a copyright with a different domain name then this is the correct source. Anyone can write/publish a jQuery library, there's no 'control' on it.

Comment: Bummer. I wish there was an official org chart from jQuery. Thanks.